# Cannot enable or restart Windows Firewall

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, firewall, services

I am trying to fix some problems related to Windows Calculator, Clock, etc., but I encounter an error while trying to run the PowerShell command:

```
Get-AppxPackage -allusers *windowscalculator* | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
```

- ```
  The package could not be installed because the Windows Firewall service is not running.
  Enable the Windows Firewall service and try again.
  ```

  To fix this problem, I uninstalled my antivirus app and have tried to apply many different approaches from [here](https://windowsreport.com/cant-activate-firewall-windows-10/), however I have not managed to activate the **Windows Defender Firewall** service: 
   [image: Screenshot]

How can I enable and start it?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122581/discussion-on-question-by-azure-cannot-enable-or-restart-windows-firewall).

Comment: Chico, I cannot comment on that page. So I have to reply using this page.

Comment: I think you have not look at this page: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-health/release-information

Comment: It says that **Semi-Annual Channel** as Servicing option. Any idea?

Comment: @azure the link you posted contains the download tool for windows 10 - in the tool, you can select the option to save to an ISO file. For your main question, if the firewall is set and locked to disabled, you probably have an antivirus program managing it. This is pretty normal, but you probably want to update to the latest build of windows 10 anyways.

Answer (score 1):

This is too late to help, but for anyone else finding this page: you would need to run regedit, find the mpssvc service under local machine\system\currentcontrolset\services

Set the start to 2 or 1 and reboot.  You can come back later and repeat by setting it back to 4 if you wanted it kept disabled.

Comment: Mine was already with 2 and it was grayed out.